# Why can't I trigger the `change` event of radio using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The page is here:

http://cistrome.org/cps/seqconfig?did=2693

And the original js codes are below(this one works well):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".open_gene").on('change', function(event) {
        $('#Gene_field').show();
    });

    $(".close_gene").on("change", function(event){
        $("#Gene_field").hide();
    });
});
```

So the `.close_gene` has an event handler for `change`. But when I want to trigger this event manually to hide the `#Gene_field`, like this:

```
>>> $('.close_gene').trigger("change")
```

In FireBugs, the returned value is:

```
[input#nolimit_radio.close_gene all]
```

But the `#Gene_field` is not hidden..

I was wondering that why I can't trigger `change` event which should already  `bind` to `function(event){ $("#Gene_field").hide();}`. Does anyone have ideas about this? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, just a friendly FYI that links to personal sites are discouraged as they break over time (as this one has).  See [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/1366033). The inlined code helps a lot, but a runnable demo in jsFiddle or stack snippets would be better. Why care at all 5 years after you've asked your question? Because future readers like me and 8,711 others still find this question when doing searches and SO isn't just a place to solve your own problems, but also to build a body of knowledge

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
$(".close_gene").click();
```

Its working fine for me in Firebug Console... :)

**Update:**

This should also work, but will not change the state of radio button

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).delegate(".open_gene",'change', function(event) {
     $('#Gene_field').show();
  });

  $(document).delegate(".close_gene", "change", function(event){
     $("#Gene_field").hide();
  });
});

$('.close_gene').trigger("change");
```

Comment: Thanks!It works. But it looks like that a `change` event should be used instead of `click` event, right? Why `$(".close_gene").change();` or `$(".close_gene").trigger("change")` wouldn't work?

Comment: @Firegun - Tired of playing with Firebug... :(